# What is the preferred way to report mass plagiarism?

Tags: support, moderation, plagiarism

Suppose you have discovered a user account that contains a significant amount of plagiarized contributions. There are hundreds upon hundreds of answers to check, and you are willing to do that, stretched over a period of time. (Although you ask yourself whether there is a point - seeing as there are probably thousands or tens of thousands of users on SO that operate the same way.... but that's a different discussion.)

What is the preferred way to report these?

- Flag each plagiarized answer separately, as they come up (the current status quo I think)
- Flag each plagiarized answer separately, as they come up, but point out that they are part of an ongoing series
- Collect plagiarized answers somewhere (where?) and report them to mods when you are done
- Some other way?

Comment: Plagiarized in what way, from another SE post or from another website?

Comment: Both, or either - it shouldn't matter though, should it? They need to be flagged either way, the question is just how

Comment: That last time I did this, I picked one plagiarized answer and flagged it explaining the situation and included links to several others. A mod nuked all of them + more.

Comment: @Mysticial yeah, I've been lucky like that as well (a mod picked up on the flags and delivered swift judgement). It'd be nice to know it's something we can always rely on (e.g. because mods can look at all flags cast against a specific user)

Comment: Is it possible to make a new flag for plagiarised work - where it would be similar to the 'duplicate' close where a link to the plagiarised content must also be included?

Comment: @Amaterasu I doubt whether it's worth the effort, seeing as the original URL is relevant only for the moderator to verify the allegation (and that can be easily done in a custom flag)

Comment: @Pëkka ah okay, just a thought (a bad one it seems)

Comment: sorry about that :)

Comment: @Amaterasu no reason! This place is there to discuss ideas. If it were on SE's agenda to make plagiarism-hunting more popular, a special flag might make sense. But I don't think it's frequent enough to warrant anything like that.

Comment: Ironically I was close to posting a feature request...lol

Comment: I like to believe this sort of behavior is grounds for account termination, but I'm not certain. What I *can* say is that as a member, your job is simply to alert us to bad behavior - if you believe a user has been doing this en masse then a single flag explaining that to us, with some examples, should suffice, similarly to how a user has been posting a lot of spam or self-promotional material. But that's just my opinion - other mods may have different ideals.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I agree that is why I suggested a means for members to identify situations where it occurs.

Comment: `if you believe a user has been doing this en masse then a single flag explaining that to us, with some examples, should suffice` so a mod would then take the 2 hours to painstakingly check the rest of the user's contributors? Really? I wouldn't mind that at all, but is that kind of detective work really something that can be expected of mods?

Comment: If this is about the user that we talked about earlier, he's been dealt with.  For users whose sole activity is plagiarism, you don't need to flag every post, just one.  Explain the problem in detail in a custom moderator flag, with an example link or two as proof.

Comment: @Robert cool, will do. There's another user who came up while researching the other's oeuvre, but he's 25% plagiarism and 75% original contributions (however low-quality) so I'll follow the "flag every post" path in that case

Comment: I cleared your active flags. A lot of those were on questions that could be closed as duplicates, which was a nice bonus. Keep them coming!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'll defer to individual mods as to their preferred ways of handling this... But I've handled a fair number of these situations now, and as far as I'm concerned, you should do one of two things:

1. If there are a large number of answers and ALL of them are plagiarized, pick one, flag it & note that ALL the answers from this user are rip-offs. Provide a link to demonstrate. I'll verify this and a few others (it is not hard) and destroy the account.
2. If it's a mix of plagiarized and original content, flag every plagiarized post. Include in each flag a link to the original. If you want to be *really* helpful, leave a comment on each post *noting* that it's plagiarized and where from. I'll delete the posts & let the author know he has to follow standard attributions rules.

Comment: This is my preferred approach.

Comment: So in other words, go through each and every one of their dozens, possibly hundreds of posts?

Comment: Realistically, @Boltclock, if someone's top-voted and most-recent posts are all rip-offs, they probably all are.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I think that cases when there are _dozens, possibly hundreds of posts_ are worth bringing to meta because there's just too mush data to carry over flags then

Comment: @gnat I did that for a while, but wasn't sure whether it's the right approach, seeing as it isn't something Meta really needs to be bothered with... but it *is* nice to have everything in one place

Comment: The thing that's most helpful to me are "other" flags that point to the original source for the content. Flagging answers as plagiarism or users as plagiarists is helpful, but the thing that saves me the most time is if the source is identified. I have a workflow for searching for this stuff, but if all I need to do is look at the linked source and identify the plagiarism I can process these flags much, much faster. I guess I'm leery of destroying accounts flagged for plagiarism unless I've checked every single answer and can verify nothing will be lost if I do this.

Comment: @Bob nice work! Hadn't heard of that.

Comment: @Bob cool, that's what I've occasionally done on my own, great to hear that it's become a crowdsourced effort. Let me know when the next hunt is on :)

Answer (score 8):

This is an expansion from the comments - one **possible** way is to make a flagging option indicating that the question or answer has been plagiarised.

A similar option could be, as I mentioned in the comments, to make the flagging similar to the 'duplicate' flag option - where a link to the plagiarised content could be provided - though I get that this may be more trouble than its worth.

Or, just use the flag --> other option.

One thing for certain, plagiarism should never be allowed and needs to be nipped in the bud so to speak when first detected, it is basically theft.  If I may be blunt, plagiarism should be dealt with as severely as spam (if not more severely).